# How to fix 'Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory',

Tags: spring, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create a simple maven project of spring-hibernate integration but getting some exception like

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError".
```

and this one as well

```
"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError".
```

.

```
applicationContext.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
        <property name="username" value="system"></property>
        <property name="password" value="admin"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="template"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />

         </bean> 

    <bean id="d" class="com.myClasses.EmployeeDao">
        <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>


</beans> 



------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EmployeeDao
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package com.myClasses;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

//import java.util.*;  

@Transactional
public class EmployeeDao 
{
    HibernateTemplate template;  
    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
        this.template = template;  
    }  

    public void saveEmployee(Employee e){  
        template.save(e);  
    }  

    /*
     * public void updateEmployee(Employee e){ template.update(e); }
     * 
     * public void deleteEmployee(Employee e){ template.delete(e); } //method to
     * return one employee of given id public Employee getById(int id){ Employee
     * e=(Employee)template.get(Employee.class,id); return e; }
     */
    //method to return all employees  
        /*
         * public List<Employee> getEmployees(){ List<Employee> list=new
         * ArrayList<Employee>(); list=template.loadAll(Employee.class); return list; }
         */  
} 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
InsertTest.java
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.myClasses;


import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class InsertTest {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    ApplicationContext factory=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    System.out.println("Running.....");

    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");  

    Employee e=new Employee();  
    e.setId(114);  
    e.setName("Abhi");  
    e.setSalary(50000);  

    System.out.println("Running.....");
    dao.saveEmployee(e);  

}  
}  


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pom.xml
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_intigration</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring_intigration Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring_intigration</finalName>
  </build>
</project>

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Employee.hbm.xml
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
<!-- Generated May 9, 2019 4:24:27 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myClasses.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="salary" type="float">
            <column name="SALARY" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Exception on Console

---

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'template' of bean class [com.myClasses.Employee]: Bean property 'template' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.myClasses.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'template' of bean class [com.myClasses.Employee]: Bean property 'template' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: As I see in your question there are multiple errors. for the error which is on the below, you should add a getter method to template object in EmployeeDao class. for the first question, there is a missing class which is not present in the runtime.

Comment: I added getter method but still there is one Exception is throwing .
.....
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.

Answer (score 0):

Put @Autowired annotation in EmployeeDao class,
 for example,

```
 class EmployeeDao{

  @Autowired
  HibernateTemplate template;

 }
```